# Do Yo and Bower overlap in terms of functionality, and if they do is there an advantage to using both?

Tags: gruntjs, workflow, gulp, yeoman, bower

I have been using Gulp for a while now and recently started using Bower. I am now looking into whether I should also be using Yo for scaffolding, but I'm not clear on the exact purpose of Yo. I'm confused because when Yo creates an app it seems to install things that I'd normally install using Bower.

**So my questions are:**

1) Is Yo actually using Bower to install these things or is it doing the installing itself, and if so does it also handle updates?

2) If so would it be possible to build a Gulp task to do the same thing as Yo is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what is [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io):

> #### What's Yeoman?
>
> Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices and tools to help you stay productive.
>
> To do so, we provide a generator ecosystem. A generator is basically a plugin that can be run with the `yo` command to scaffold complete projects or useful parts.

About your questions:

1. Yeoman uses Bower:

   > The Yeoman workflow comprises three types of tools for improving your productivity and satisfaction when building a web app: the scaffolding tool (yo), the build tool (Grunt, Gulp, etc) and the package manager (like Bower and npm).
2. The goal of Yeoman is different of Grunt or Gulp. It doesn't intent to substitute gulp or grunt, but to make it easy to use them. So I would say *yes, it's possible* to make a gulp task that creates the scaffolding, but I strongly recommend you to not do it. Don't reinvent the wheel, a lot of people had make many Yeoman generators to help with almost everything web-related.

Yeoman is really useful to start a new project. Even more if you don't know the technology and you want some help with the scaffolding of the project. There are many examples, like a [Chrome Extension generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension), an [Angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular), a [Firefox Extension generator](https://github.com/dgil/generator-firefox-extension/) and [many more](http://yeoman.io/generators/).

Comment: Thanks no I had no intention of starting a gulpfile for doing that ... I was just confused as they seem to be doing similar things ... but I'm guessing yo is purpose built whereas a gulp file would be ad hoc?